# why cant i send emails using nodemailer and nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, smtp, nodemailer

I'm trying to send email using node.js and nodemailer but when I'm pressing the submit button its just loading and loading and in the end gives me a "504 Gateway Timeout Error" in the server, and "page is not working" locally.

I'm using the following code:

```js
app.post("/postmail", function (req, res) {
  var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: "smtp.mailtrap.io",
    port: 2525,
    secure: false,
    debug: true,
    auth: {
      user: "xxx",
      password: "xxx",
    },
  });

  var message = {
    from: "a@b", // Sender address
    to: "b@c", // List of recipients
    subject: "Design Your Model S | Tesla", // Subject line
    text: "Have the most fun you can in a car. Get your Tesla today!", // Plain text body
  };

  transporter.sendMail(message, function (err, info) {
    if (err) {
      console.log(err);
    } else {
      console.log(info);
      res.render("landing");
    }
  });
});
```

I must also mention that, I tried multiple smtp servers with multiple ports and configuration.

does someone know what to do?

thanks

Comment: UPDATE i tried the following setting:

      tls: {
            rejectUnauthorized: false
        } 

and changed the property
"password"
to "pass".
now its working only locally, i'm still getting the same error on the server.
i tried to change the property host to :

  host: "host"
but its still not working

Comment: P.S 
now i'm getting the "0|app  | ] code: 'ESOCKET', command: 'CONN' }" error

Answer (score 0):

cuase all of the smtp providers use tls/ssl for secuirity reasons. try to use secure configuration:

```
var transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    host: 'smtp.mailtrap.io',
    port: 465,
    secure: true,    
    debug: true,
    auth: {    
        user: 'xxx',
        password: 'xxx'
    }
});
```

Comment: no, still not working, its stuck, loading and loading ending with the errors i mentioned above